# IFRAME Outlook Calendar (Office365)

Tags: php, html, xml

I'm building a script which jumps around to `index.php?p=1  - 3` which loads the calendars in what I hoped would be an iframe however Ive just found out that they are blocked.

Is there any alternative?

Comment: alternatives to? its not clear what you want to do

Comment: It is clear... I've said I wanted an iframe (Office 365) which displays the calendar from their site however its being blocked.

Comment: Well if you say its clear carry on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From this link, it would appear that it is not possible to display the calendar in an iFrame. Suggested workarounds would be displaying the calendar in a pop-up window?

Blocking calendar in an iFrame appears to be by Microsoft's design: [see here](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/162063/can-not-get-iframe-to-load-outlook-365-calendar)

Comment: glad to here it, iframes should never be used ever.

Comment: I agree, but the reason why I want an iframe is because we have 3 calendars which we will be rotating and will be casted over to a TV using a Chromecast (but the calendar needs to rotate :(

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any alternative?

As I have explained in other questions asking for alternatives, the answer on a programming Q&A site always is: *"Most likely yes"*.

Then a reflection often by the OP, *"if so, then how?"* and for sure luckily the answer again is quickly available for a programming Q&A site: *"It's most likely done by programming"*. Or in our modern times: *"You need to find the webservice that does it for you"*.

From the very little detail you give in your question, you could proxy the request to the data and scrape the data in a manner that is not blocked by Outlook Calendar (Office365).

From the context information you provide in comments, take care that the amount of work you might need to put into that would overgo the amount of work budgeted to you for it.

So yes, it's possible, but most likely it's not practicable feasible. This is because the vendor of *Outlook Calendar (Office365)* does not want you as one of the software users to easily integrate with it. So please don't moan here on Stackoverflow that it's complicated, but write to customer support as you've bought that software and plug a feature request.